# Sharepoint : create a new file in a specific drive with graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

In order to create a new file in a drive (a simple text file with some content), I try to call an API with MS Graph.

```
PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
```

The drive where I want to put the file is name "myFolder" and has this driveId :

```
b!e5bDF5eRbU2Y7P3gHeS-0F1abPhpWXdOvSUViyWpqX876IbeJvIPS5-tf--QTQiz
```

This drive is in the root site.

Here :

- {site-id} : "root"
- {parent-id} : is the id of the drive which will be the parent
- {filename} : text.txt

If I had to create this file in a subsite it would

- {site-id}:/sites/{subsite-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content

So theoretically my URL should be the following :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives/b!e5bDF5eRbU2Y7P3gHeS-0F1abPhpWXdOvSUViyWpqX876IbeJvIPS5-tf--QTQiz:/text.txt:/content
```

Here :

- {site-id} : "root"
- {parent-id} : is the id of the drive which will be the parent
- {filename} : text.txt

I also define the request header Content-Type as text/plain
My issue is that I retrieve an error message :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'content'.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-06-26T14:19:11",
      "request-id": "812b7ee0-3ecb-4d41-a8c5-59419b086f51"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected error since for addressing a file within a drive (which is `document library` in SharePoint) a folder container needs to be provided:

So, instead of query

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives/{drive-id}:/{file-name}:/content
```

it should be

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{folder-path}/{file-name}:/content
```

where folder-path corresponds to `Test` folder in your case

**References**

[Addressing resources in a drive on OneDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/addressing-driveitems?view=odsp-graph-online)

Comment: It works perfectly thanks ! I also solved how to create a MS office document with content ...

Comment: @davidvera how did you create a new MS Office document?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly create file in subsite library using below endpoints:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{sub-siteid}/drives/{driveid}/root:/FolderA/FileB.txt:/content`

Reference doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-upload-a-new-file

And if you want to get subsite id, you can refer to :

- [Access a site by server-relative URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#access-a-site-by-server-relative-url)

Demo request:
[image]